# How to get the TestCategory name from TestContext in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework, vstest.console.exe

I have a test method with TestCategory attribute as shown below.

```
<TestMethod()> <TestCategory("myCategory")>
Public Sub TestString()
   Dim a as String="a"
   Dim b as String="b"
   Assert.AreEqual(a,b)
End Sub
```

can we get the test category name (`myCategory`) using `TestContext` in `AssemblyInitialize` method?

Thanks in advance..